# Latch-up and ESD protection for power supply and RS-422

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, low-power, emc, esd

I am designing a power supply board that has a switching regulator and four [LDOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-dropout_regulator). Now, I understand that layout details or practices will help reduce switching noise from corrupting the ground and so on and so forth.

I have been asked to do a study on latch-up and prevent latch-up of the board in question. As far as I understand, latch-up is a behaviour that corrupts or damages ICs and that preventive measures are taken care of in silicon by the VLSI designer to prevent latch-up.

How can I make my design latch-up proof? I also believed that in case of PCBs, it was ESD that was the killer. How or what are the things that I can include in the power suppy (regulator and LDO) design that can make my design more stable?

The board also has an UART-to-RS-422 level shifter as well. It will take single-ended UART signals and convert them into differential RS-422-level signals.

I understand that EMC or ESD analysis and protection is a vast subject. But any pointers that shall help me begin are appreciated, please.

Comment: I almost feel like this is two questions not one. On the subject of ESD I had a board recently where the prototypes had FETs failing due to ESD and we had to add TVS diodes to the gates of the FETs. With ESD it really depends on what needs protection and what kind of ESD events it will be seeing. It might be better to make a new question for the ESD portion and include more information on what parts you are protecting and what kind of environment the PCB will be in.

Comment: A large number of RS-422 and RS-232 transceivers are available with up to 15kV (human body model) protection; whether this is sufficient for you I cannot say without more detail. I will note that IEC61000-4-2 (used at system level) is somewhat more stringent.